# Why is this ambiguous?

Tags: php, sql

When I query this:

```
$result = pg_query($dbconn, 
"SELECT w_bildurl, 
w_homepage_package_id AS whpi                         

FROM adempiere.w_homepage_package                           
LEFT JOIN adempiere.w_homepage_image ON adempiere.w_homepage_package.w_homepage_package_id = adempiere.w_homepage_image.w_homepage_package_id
LEFT JOIN adempiere.w_bilder ON adempiere.w_homepage_image.w_bilder_id = adempiere.w_bilder.w_bilder_id
WHERE sequence > 0
ORDER BY sequence ASC");
```

I get

```
 Query failed: ERROR: column reference 
"w_homepage_package_id" is ambiguous LINE 1:
 SELECT w_bildurl, w_homepage_package_id AS whpi
```

I thought that adding the alias to w_homepage_package_id would prevent ambiguity. Do I have to add the alias to the LEFT JOIN or how can I get that w_homepage_package_id from the query?

Comment: I don't think you understand. It doesn't know what table `w_homepage_package_id` to grab the column from, as it exists multiple places. Put a table name in front of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you didn't specify table to which this column belongs to.
The following code would work:

```
  SELECT w_bildurl, 
         adempiere.w_homepage_package.w_homepage_package_id AS whpi                         
    FROM adempiere.w_homepage_package                           
         LEFT JOIN adempiere.w_homepage_image 
                   ON adempiere.w_homepage_package.w_homepage_package_id = adempiere.w_homepage_image.w_homepage_package_id
         LEFT JOIN adempiere.w_bilder 
                   ON adempiere.w_homepage_image.w_bilder_id = adempiere.w_bilder.w_bilder_id
   WHERE sequence > 0
ORDER BY sequence ASC
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to prepend table alias since the same column is in more than one table, so change as follow

```
SELECT tablealis.w_bildurl, 
tablealias.w_homepage_package_id AS whpi
```

Just change `tablealias` with actual table alias of the tables those column belong to

Answer (score 1):

you have to use alias for better use, i have implemented your code

```
<?php 

$result = pg_query($dbconn, 
"SELECT a.*,b.*,c.*                         

FROM adempiere.w_homepage_package as a                           
LEFT JOIN adempiere.w_homepage_image as b ON a.w_homepage_package_id = b.w_homepage_package_id
LEFT JOIN adempiere.w_bilder as c ON b.w_bilder_id = c.w_bilder_id
WHERE sequence > 0
ORDER BY sequence ASC");
```